# Excel Formula for Matching Cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, spreadsheet, formula

I have an excel spreadsheet as such:

```
 - A  Column A - AB 12
 - B  Column B - AB 12
 - C  Does Column A match Column B? - Y
```

However, the column information is being pulled via query, from a database system and sometimes the values are as such:

```
 - A  Column A - AB12
 - B  Column B - AB 12
 - C  Does Column A match Column B? - N
```

I actuallity they do match and I need to accomodate for that? is it possible to do so? my current column 3 has this formula:

`=IF(A3=B3,"Y","N")`

that returns a no when it should be a yes. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... You could always use the `Substitute` function to remove all the spaces from your cells before comparing them:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","")=SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",""), "Y", "N")
```

Comment: +1 since that's the exact answer I tried to give before I was blocked by the captcha and didn't notice. :)

Comment: Had that happen to me a bunch of times - I'm just glad you agree with my solution :)